# É necessário o uso de alguma ferramenta de CI para construir e buildar o docker-compose com maven?

Tags: java, maven, docker

Eu estou construindo uma aplicação web com Spring MVC e Postgres, meu problema aqui é com o uso do pom.xml criar um docker-compose file para fazer o deploy em containers. É possível adicionar comandos ao pom.xml para que ele consigo realizar essas tarefas no comando ‘mvn build’ ou eu teria que depender de alguma outra ferramenta de Integração Contínua? Ainda não conheço muito sobre o Maven. Já procurei em documentações e outras fontes mas sem muito sucesso

Comment: brodi, eu sei que da, mas nunca fiz, tem vários links na internet explicando como faz, pesquisa por mvn build docker, que você acha, não me leve a mal, não estou explicando como faz, porque não sei fazer mesmo haha

Comment: Eu acabei achando um plugin pro maven chamado spotify, ainda estou estudando pra ver se serve ao meu propósito